# VBA Code to Save Workbook as Folder Name

Tags: vba, excel

I query an xls file and save it to a folder. This folder is at the end of many folders and I want code to save it using the prior folders name (guessing I need a relative path that only goes back one folder) & the current folders name & the current date, in an xlsm format so I can use macros on it later.

For example:
Prior Folder's name is "Main Folder"
Current Folder's name is "Program"
Date is "01/22/2016"

I want it save as "Main Folder Program 01.22.16" as an xlsm file

I have saved to specific locations before, but this is different because I need it to be a relative reference because I do this procedure dozens of times/day for different reports.

Excel 2013

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Path` will tell you where the workbook is located -

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this might be a little bit ugly as a solution, but it works for me. Note that I'm on my mac so path is given with : and it might be / on Windows from memory. So just update that. But...:

```
Dim str As String
Dim today As Date
Dim x As Integer

today = Now()
str = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
x = InStrRev(str, ":", InStrRev(str, ":") - 1)
str = Mid(str, x + 1)
str = Replace(str, ":", " ")
str = str + " " + Format(today, "dd.mm.yyyy")
```

Comment: i am not sure about mac, but it looks like mac use different path separator `":"` compared to windows that use `"\"`. Use `Application.PathSeparator` to overcome the difference.

Comment: yeah, I did mention I thought it was different and adjust accordingly. The `Application.PathSeparator` just returns what it is doesn't it? Rather than overcoming it per se.

Comment: Names file and saves as an xlsm, but it saves it to my documents folder and not the folder where it got the folder names. Do you know what I need to add to fix the file path? 
Dim str As String
Dim today As Date
Dim x As Integer
'Saves excel file and names it the prior folder, current folder, and current date
today = Now()
str = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
x = InStrRev(str, "\", InStrRev(str, "\") - 1)
str = Mid(str, x + 1)
str = Replace(str, "\", " ")
str = str + " " + Format(today, "mm.dd.yyyy")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=str & “.xlsm”, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled